# Could not authenticate with OAuth error when passing parameters Twitter API

Tags: twitter, twitter-oauth

I am getting "Could not authenticate with OAuth" error when i pass parameters to the Twitter API. if i don't pass any parameter then it works fine.

Can anybody look into this issue and provide me the solution.

My OAuth request array is as below

```
Array
(

[method] => GET
[uri] => Array
(
    [host] => api.twitter.com
    [path] => 1/direct_messages.json
)

[auth] => Array
(
    [method] => OAuth
    [oauth_token] => 605267577-YwEtkLXgDZcXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
    [oauth_token_secret] => p2SKUjaRz7oUqW8jmXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
    [oauth_consumer_key] => PAu4LlcETXXXXXXXXXXXXX
    [oauth_consumer_secret] => OA2ISmIYMXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
)

[body] => Array
(
    [count] => 200
)

[header] => Array
(
    [Authorization] => OAuth oauth_version="1.0",oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",oauth_token="605267577-YwEtkLXgDZcLaFIZHdJxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",oauth_consumer_key="PAu4LlcETSxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",oauth_nonce="616caa42455f6a490f7fce089fdb56b5",oauth_timestamp="1342592116",oauth_signature="B2Dr4CioXL55fwxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
)

)
```

i passed the "count" parameter and this is response that i got

```
Array
(
    [error] => Could not authenticate with OAuth.
    [request] => /1/direct_messages.json
)
```

Thanks in advance,
Intekhab

Answer (score 0):

You do not authenticate correctly. You have to follow this process : https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/authorizing-request

Comment: Thanks for reply, but i still couldn't understand the problem. Would you please tell where is the problem in my code.

Comment: Please check my request now in question, i am using all the OAuth parameters.

Comment: There are spaces after commas in the `Authorization` header. About the rest of your code, it seems OK. I guess that you do the right things for signing your request.

Comment: There are no spaces after commas in my code, and same header works if don't pass any parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem until I found out that API needs to have that parameter in oauth array and in URL query.